# Как увеличить частоту обновления события mouseMoveEvent в PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview, mousemoveevent

Здесь при нажатии и движении мышки рисуются очень маленькие линии в `QGraphicsScene`, которые соединяются друг с другом:

```
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.black)
        self.brush = QBrush(Qt.black)
        self.lastScenePos = 0
        self.currentScenePos = 0

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        x = event.scenePos().x()
        y = event.scenePos().y()
        self.lastScenePos = (x, y)
        self.currentScenePos = (x, y)
        self.addEllipse(*self.lastScenePos, 1, 1, self.pen)
        print(x, y)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        x = event.scenePos().x()
        y = event.scenePos().y()
        self.currentScenePos = (x, y)
        print(self.lastScenePos, 'last')
        print(self.currentScenePos, 'cur')
        print('---')
        self.addLine(QLineF(*self.lastScenePos, *self.currentScenePos), self.pen)
        self.lastScenePos = (x, y)
```

Но в моей программе я добавил возможность зумировать `QGraphicsView`. 
При приближении видно такую неприятную картину:

[image]

И я бы хотел рисовать с помощью множества точек, чтобы это лучше выглядело, но если я быстро двигаю мышку, то линия разрывается на отдельные точки.

Как я понимаю, надо увеличить частоту `mouseMoveEvent`, чтобы линия не разрывалась. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вставил ваш класс в код и очень быстро двигаю мышку. 
И чем быстрее двигаю, тем красивее получается и ничего не разрывается.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.red, 3)
        self.brush = QBrush(Qt.black)
        self.lastScenePos = 0
        self.currentScenePos = 0

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        x = event.scenePos().x()
        y = event.scenePos().y()
        self.lastScenePos = (x, y)
        self.currentScenePos = (x, y)
        self.addEllipse(*self.lastScenePos, 1, 1, self.pen)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        x = event.scenePos().x()
        y = event.scenePos().y()
        self.currentScenePos = (x, y)
        self.addLine(QLineF(*self.lastScenePos, *self.currentScenePos), self.pen)
        self.lastScenePos = (x, y)


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        scene = GraphicsScene(self)   
        self.setScene(scene)
        self._pixmap_item = self.scene().addPixmap(QPixmap())
        self._pixmap_item.setZValue(-1)
        self.__zoom = 0

    @property
    def pixmap(self):
        return self._pixmap_item.pixmap()

    @pixmap.setter
    def pixmap(self, pixmap):
        self._pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.scene().setSceneRect(self._pixmap_item.boundingRect())

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            factor = 1.25
            self.__zoom += 1
        else:
            factor = 0.8
            self.__zoom -= 1
        self.scale(factor, factor)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.view = GraphicsView(self)
        self.view.pixmap = QPixmap("im.png") 

        addLine = QPushButton("AddLine")
        addLine.clicked.connect(self.addLine)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.view)
        hbox.addWidget(addLine)
        
    def addLine(self):
        self.pen = QPen(QColor("#FF00E4"), 7)
        self.view.scene().addLine(0, 0, 600, 600, self.pen)
        self.view.scene().addLine(600, 600, 20, 200, self.pen)
        self.view.scene().addLine(20, 200, 400, 40, self.pen)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, если я начинаю рисовать медленно, то линия превращается в какого-то ёжика: [https://ibb.co/56Jkxw9]

Comment: @TAWER768 ... быстро двигаю мышку, то линия разрывается на отдельные точки.
... если я начинаю рисовать медленно, то линия превращается в какого-то ёжика. 
Вам не угодишь :)

Comment: Так сейчас там не рисуются точки. Там рисуются линии, которые соединяются друг с другом. При приближении они выглядят как ёжики. Я пытался сделать так, чтобы это рисовалось отдельными точками, но тогда при быстром движении мышки линия на кружки разрывалась. Вот я и хотел бы увеличить частоту ивента.